# How Can I Match Orders to Products?

Tags: database, vb.net, linq, list, dataset

I have a set of Orders, each with a desired weight, and a set of Turkeys, each with a weight, all contained in a database and dataset, but accessed via objects (This makes it more complicated, but the objects are there to increase the complexity of the project, rather than because it's a good idea).

How can I match them, then update the database and dataset? I'm trying to do it with lists and LINQ, but it's not working so well. Unfortunately, I can't see where I'm going wrong.
EDIT: The line
    `For Count = 0 To Max - 1
            Orders.UpdateOrder(Count, Count + 1, Orders.OrderDetail(Count, "CustomerID"), TurkeyList(Count)(0), Orders.OrderDetail(Count, "ApproxWeight"))
        Next` Has an index out of bounds error. I know what this means, but I can't see why I'm getting it, and how to fix it.

I HAVE done my research - in fact, my current attempt uses lists (which I had never heard of until I read that I could use them for this on StackOverflow) but, tbh, this isn't something I've been taught, and I could use some guidance. I originally tried using 2-dimensional arrays, which didn't work. I THINK that my current implementation should work - so there's a good chance that I'm just missing something stupid.
Below is the relevant part of my code.

```
Imports System.Linq
# <summary>
#  SortForm is a public class which handles the events and controls of a single form.
#  </summary>
#  <remarks></remarks>
Public Class SortForm
    Dim Turkeys As New TurkeyDBInteract
    Dim Orders As New OrderDBInteract
    Dim Customers As New CustomerDBInteract
    Public TurkeyList As New List(Of Integer())
    Public OrderList As New List(Of Integer())
    #  <summary>
    #  The FillLists subroutine fills the two lists with data from the dataset.
    #  </summary>
    #  <remarks></remarks>
    Public Sub FillLists()
        For Count = 0 To Orders.OrderNum - 1
            OrderList.Add(New Integer() {Count, Orders.OrderDetail(Count, "ApproxWeight")})
        Next
        For Count = 0 To Turkeys.TurkeyNum - 1
            TurkeyList.Add(New Integer() {Count, Turkeys.TurkeyDetail(Count, "Weight")})
        Next
    End Sub
    #  <summary>
    #  The SortList subroutine takes a List of 1-dimensional integer and sorts it using LINQ to Objects.
    #  </summary>
    #  <param name="List"></param>
    #  <remarks></remarks>
    Public Sub SortList(ByRef List As List(Of Integer()))
        Dim SortedList As New List(Of Integer())
        SortedList = List.OrderBy(Function(Weight) Weight(1)).ToList()
        List = SortedList
    End Sub
    #  <summary>
    #  This is the SortButton click event. This calls the <see cref="FillLists"/> and <see cref="SortList"/> subroutines to process order and turkey data, then matches the lists and uses this to update the dataset and database.
    #  </summary>
    #  <param name="sender"></param>
    #  <param name="e"></param>
    #  <remarks></remarks>
    Private Sub SortButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SortButton.Click
        FillLists()
        SortList(TurkeyList)
        SortList(OrderList)
        Dim Max As Integer
        If TurkeyList.Count > OrderList.Count Then
            Max = OrderList.Count
        Else
            Max = TurkeyList.Count
        End If
        For Count = 0 To Max - 1
            Orders.UpdateOrder(Count, Count + 1, Orders.OrderDetail(Count, "CustomerID"), TurkeyList(Count)(0), Orders.OrderDetail(Count, "ApproxWeight"))
        Next
   End Sub
End Class
```

Here is the code for the OrderUpdate method from the OrderDBInteract class

```
    # <summary>
    # Subroutine UpdateOrder updates every value of a specific record of the OrderTbl dataset table and then updates the database.
    # </summary>
    # <param name="Row">Row passes the row of the record to be updated.</param>
    # <param name="OrderID">OrderID passes the new primary key value of the record to be updated.</param>
    # <param name="CustomerID">CustomerID passes the new foreign key field value of the record to be updated.</param>
    # <param name="ApproxWeight">ApproxWeight passes a new field value of the record to be updated.</param>
    # <remarks></remarks>
    Public Sub UpdateOrder(ByVal Row, ByVal OrderID, ByVal CustomerID, ByVal TurkeyID, ByVal ApproxWeight)
        Data.Tables("OrderTbl").Rows(Row).Item("OrderID") = OrderID
        Data.Tables("OrderTbl").Rows(Row).Item("CustomerID") = CustomerID
        Data.Tables("OrderTbl").Rows(Row).Item("TurkeyID") = TurkeyID
        Data.Tables("OrderTbl").Rows(Row).Item("ApproxWeight") = ApproxWeight
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try a [sortedlist](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist.aspx) that sorts values according to keys. For instance:

```
Dim OrderList As New SortedList
    For Count = 0 To Orders.OrderNum - 1
        OrderList.Add(Orders.OrderDetail(Count, "ApproxWeight"), Count)
    Next
```

will sort values (Count) according to the result of Orders.OrderDetail. That way you need not to call the SortList method.

Although, this

```
Data.Tables("OrderTbl").Rows(Row).Item("OrderID") = OrderID
```

does change the OrderID column value of the Row in the dataset's table, these changes do not get committed to database. Have a look at this [msdn walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzb1zw3x%28v=vs.80%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)
about saving data to database. Basically, you need a DataAdapter with an appropriate UpdateCommand setup to update database table with changes from dataset. If you're using a typed dataset in your program then committing changes to database becomes an easier task.